# Unable to create the MySQL database on linux server

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-grant, mysql-error-1044

I have only one user. I am logged with the same user and tried to create the database and getting the following error.

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'csatsurvey'@'localhost' to database 'demo'
```

By the above error I understood that I am have some access issues. How can I grant the permissions and crate the database with the same user.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

step 1: login to your mysql -u root -p

step 2: basic syntax to permission
 "GRANT permission ON database.table TO 'user'@'localhost';"

step 3: To grant any specific permission 
GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO 'testuser'@'localhost';
CREATE is a permission

to more details visit to 
http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/grant-permissions-to-a-mysql-user-on-linux-via-command-line/

Comment: can you see my screenshot, I have only one user. How can I login with root user?

Comment: You don't have a root user.Please check by this "mysql> SELECT User, Host, Password FROM mysql.user;"